# Calculate average of two data fields php/mysql

Tags: php, sql, dataformat

I wonder know how to deal data format. I have 2 columns **date(starting date)** **date2 (end date)**. I am not familiar with php/mysql.

one my biggest clue is the **data/data2** fields appears on this format ie. "1394797440". I am trying to build a dashboard with DB graphics of a ticket support. Had some features done but the **data format** is stressing me up. let me know if I am right.

I need to do a foreach on both fields? sorry my noob question but I am totally lost :|

mostly I use this call->    `$call_date = date("m/d/y",$site_calls->call_date);`

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code is correct. What's the problem You are facing?

Comment: Hi, Ripa, I am trying to "extract" two date columns, one is starting date ($call_date), and other ending date "$call_date2). I want to build a query to calculate average of both date. I have this at the moment; $call_date = $db->get_var("select call_date from site_calls");
$call_date2 = $db->get_var("select call_date2 from site_calls");
$avr_date = (($call_date2 - $call_date));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UNIX epoch datetime format i.e. number of seconds elapsed since 1st Jan, 1970. To take average of the two dates, it is similar to any other numeric average.

```
$avg_date = $site_calls->call_date + (($site_calls->call_date2 - $site_calls->call_date)/2);
$call_date = date("m/d/y",$avg_date);
```

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The data/data2 format is most likely Unix epoch time. It is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 and can be converted to an actual date and time.